# RXJS cancel subscriptions when new value is available

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

The problem: I currently have use an observable to request game data from my API. 
It requests this every time the user switches from game to game, but if the user's internet connection is too slow to keep up with rapid game changes it displays previously requested data.

```
this.gamesService.selectedGame.subscribe((selectedGame) => {
  // Reset current value
  this.setRounds(null);

  // Fetch new game values
  if (selectedGame) {
    this.apiService.get(`Games/${selectedGame.IntGameID}`)
      .subscribe(
        data => this.setRounds(data)
      );
  }
});
```

`gamesService.selectedGame` outputs a value every time the user switches to a different game. I am looking for a way to cancel the previous "subscription" and only run this piece of code for the most up to date request.

Comment: What is the implementation of selectedGame? Do you use subject or subscription here?

Comment: That's the whole purpose of the switchMap operator. https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As JB nizet pointed out I indeed needed to use the `switchMap` operator. This resulted in the following code.

```
this.gamesService.selectedGame.pipe(switchMap(
  (selectedGame) => {
    // Reset current value
    this.setRounds(null);

    // Fetch new game values
    return this.apiService.get(`Games/${selectedGame.IntGameID}`);
  })).subscribe(
    data => this.setRounds(data)
  );
```